# Запуск nHibernate без некоторых маппингов

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Пишу плагины, которые сами рулят своим маппингом в базу. Подключение решается легко, сущности сохраняются, всё работает как надо.

Вопрос прост - как сделать плагины отключаемыми, всмысле созданные в базе данные - игнорируемыми?

Сейчас при обращении к сущности, для которой не загружен маппинг падает ошибка:

> NHibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 1 was not of the
>   specified subclass: $ClassName (Discriminator
>   was: 'f526cd85-7846-4f32-85a7-c57e3983dfb1')    в
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetInstanceClass(IDataReader rs, Int32 i,
>   ILoadable persister, Object id, ISessionImplementor session)

А меня бы больше устроило, если бы он реагировал так, будто записи и вовсе нет в базе.

В дополнение к вышенаписанному - маплю в одну табличку все реализации конкретного интерфейса, т.е. Table Per Class Hierarchy. Пока обращения идут типизированные (конкретный класс) или по `id` - всё ок, когда просто запрашивается вся табличка по интерфейсу - падает на незамапленных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, благодаря подсказке товарища [kmv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557684/196257) удалось набросать работающий вариант.

После загрузки маппингов в `ExposeConfiguration` можно добавить фильтров.

```
  foreach (var source in config.ClassMappings.Where(m => m.Discriminator != null && m is RootClass))
  {
    source.Where = string.Format("{0} in ('{1}')", 
      source.Discriminator.ColumnIterator.Single().Text,
      string.Join("', '", source.SubclassIterator.Select(i => i.DiscriminatorValue)));
  }
```

Расчет строго на простой дискриминатор, хотя судя по API, они могут быть и составными. Сабклассы уже загружены, а потому всегда можно добавить явный фильтр по ним. Условия `m.Discriminator != null` и `m is RootClass` обязательны, первый - для собственно фильтрации по полю, второй - для определения того, что это корневой маппинг. Сабклассы фильтровать толи нельзя, толи нет смысла, уже не помню.

Если какая то сущность держит ссылку на такой объект, то для неё надо не забыть добавить игнор на событие `NotFound`:

```
  References(x => x.Login).Cascade.All().NotFound.Ignore();
```

Теперь стоит учитывать, что даже если поле заполняется всегда, то в такой реализации из базы может вернуться и `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что штатными средствами проигнорировать дискриминатор не получится. Можно попробовать использовать фильтр на мэппинге, примерно так:

```
var cfg = new Configuration();

// здесь настраиваем конфигурацию, подключаем плагины

// GetPluginsGuid возвращает GUID-ы всех подключенных плагинов
IEnumerable<Guid> discriminators = GetPluginsGuid();

var mapping = cfg.GetClassMapping(typeof(IPluginInterface));

// поле-дискриминатор
var discriminatorColumn = mapping.Discriminator.ColumnIterator.First().Text;

mapping.Where = String.Format("{0} IN ('{1}')",
        discriminatorColumn,
        String.Join("','", discriminators));

// ...
```

После этого из результатов запросов исчезнут строки с невалидными значениями дискриминаторов.

Также, чтобы не возникали исключения при обращении из других сущностей с невалидным значением внешнего ключа, нужно установить на соответствующей ассоциации атрибут `not-found="ignore"`:

```
<many-to-one name="SomeAssociation" class="IPluginInterface" ... not-found="ignore">
```

Comment: Идею уловил, всегда where по доступным дискриминаторам. Это взлетело, спасибо. Может сможете подсказать, как обрабатывать `NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists`, который возникает при ссылке на пропущенную запись? Или это намек на то, что я неправильно модель построил и надо что-то делать с моделью?

Comment: @Monk а это при каком действии происходит? `session.Get` или `Query` просто null возвращают.

Comment: Грузится другая сущность, у которой в базе ссылка на пропускаемую сущность. В итоге просто падает материализация: http://pastebin.com/XSY3TG4x

Comment: @Monk действительно, это получается битое значение внешнего ключа. У вас в этой другой сущности ассоциация (`many-to-one`) на сущность плагинов? Тогда нужно поставить на нее атрибут `not-found="ignore"`

Comment: Во fluent сделал вот так и оно хотя бы не сыплется, да `References(x => x.Login).Cascade.All().NotFound.Ignore();`

Comment: Мне это оформить своим ответом или вы актуализируете? Если актуализация, то название колонки с типом можно достать из коллекции `Discriminator.ColumnIterator` у маппинга.